# Sharing Rule based on lookup field

Tags: sharing-rule

I am attempting to create a Sharing Rule which will simply share a record with whomever is in a certain User lookup field on the record. What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an app to solve this problem. Its called Unleash Your Formula https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000MS8T1EAL.

It simply copies and syncs formula fields to non-formula fields. This allows you to use the synced "static" (non-formula) field in your sharing rules. Voila.

Comment: Awesome ! I can remember writing this question 4+ years ago. haha I'll have to try out Unleash Your Formula ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You cannot used owner based sharing because it does not fit your need and you cannot use criteria based sharing because you wont get option to share with a user with a custom lookup field .

So we are left with two options

1.Simple trigger

2.A process builder that will look up the custom user field and create a share record .

Comment: Yes so every object has a share object .Share object is a junction between your object and the user you want to share the record .you just need to create __share records

Comment: The object is Policy__c and I don't see a Policy__share available when attempting to create a new record in process builder.

Comment: You may have to invoke a flow and flow might have it .You can create a simple trigger instead and that's easier or invoke apex via process builder

Comment: oh well, I'm not going to go with the Apex solution. I think I will end up using criteria sharing to assign it to a Role instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how "Unleash Your Formula" is a solution for this question since nothing on the appexchange description explains how it is solved.
Can someone please elaborate?

The main question is whether one can share a record directly with a user identified in the LOOKUP field on a given object and as @Mohith Shrivastava correctly pointed out, there are NO options to share a record directly with a user whether using Ownership-based or Criteria-based sharing rules. This is because the only options listed under "Select the users to share with" include the following:

1. Portal Roles
2. Portal Roles and Subordinates
3. Public Groups
4. Roles
5. Roles and Internal Subordinates
6. Roles, Internal and Portal Subordinates
7. Territories
8. Territories and Subordinates

Solution# 1 (Fully Declarative): You can use a Flow to create the Share record for the user associated with the lookup field.

Solution# 2 (Programmatic): As Mohit shared, create a trigger on the target object to create a SHARE record for the user identified on the Lookup field on the target object.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! *Firstly*, the "Unleash Your Formula" answer explains how it helps - you can't use Formula fields in Sharing Rules, but you can use a Formula field to determine the User and the synced field from the app can be used in the Sharing Rule. *Secondly*, the answer part of your answer seems no different from Mohith's; can you please explain how it is different?